# Convert loop output to a list python

Tags: python, list

I have this loop:

```
features = ['ca','tf','se','zz','rd','fbs','th','ex']
for i in range(1, len(features) + 1):  # iterate and select next features
    Sbest = [] 
    input_f = features[:i]
    y = data['target']
    X = data[input_f] 
    model_= KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=100)
    model_.fit(X)
    precision,recall,fscore,support=score(y,model_.labels_,average='macro')
    Sbest.append(input_f)
    Sbest.append(round(fscore,2))
    print(Sbest)
```

that gives me this output:

```
[['ca'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se'], 0.71]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz'], 0.71]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd'], 0.42]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs'], 0.12]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th'], 0.56]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th', 'ex'], 0.56]
```

but what I really want is that output could be a list as I want to sort it later;
What I want is something like this:

```
[
[['ca'], 0.62],
[['ca', 'tf'], 0.62],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se'], 0.71],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz'], 0.71],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd'], 0.42],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs'], 0.12],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th'], 0.56],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th', 'ex'], 0.56]
]
```

How do I convert this to a list?

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: Just put it into a list `a = [a]`

Comment: @ti7, I tried, it doen't help.

Comment: what about `a=[]; a.append(sbest)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy thing you could do is creating a list outside the loop and appending each of your `Sbest` lists to it.

Something like this:

```
my_list = []
features = ['ca','tf','se','zz','rd','fbs','th','ex']
for i in range(1, len(features) + 1):  # iterate and select next features
    Sbest = [] 
    input_f = features[:i]
    y = data['target']
    X = data[input_f] 
    model_= KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=100)
    model_.fit(X)
    precision,recall,fscore,support=score(y,model_.labels_,average='macro')
    Sbest.append(input_f)
    Sbest.append(round(fscore,2))
    print(Sbest)
    my_list.append(Sbest)
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that outside of/before the for loop, you create an empty list

```
a = []
```

Then at the end of the for loop, immediately before or after the print(sbest) you add a line for

```
a.append(sbest)
```